# Trigger Callback on new message with MQTT paho async publish

Tags: c, eclipse, callback, mqtt, paho

I am using the MQTTAsync_publish.c sample code from MQTT paho. What I did is I replaced the constant PAYLOAD in the sample code with an SendMessageArray. The content of this array changes in my other code if a new radio message arrives. The payload gets send successfully upon first connect.

**However I do not understand how I trigger a new publish when my payload changes?**

The function MQTTAsync_sendMessage is triggered within the onConnect callback so I just somehow have to trigger this callback again, but how. If I change the sample code to stay connected after first send by not calling the onSend callback, then with finished=0 it is "Waiting for publication of %s on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n", but I cannot place the new payload.

```
volatile MQTTAsync_token deliveredtoken;
char SendMessageArray[4096] = { 0 };  // global
int finished = 0;

void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);

    printf("Reconnecting\n");
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        finished = 1;
    }
}


void onDisconnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("Successful disconnection\n");
    finished = 1;
}


void onSend(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions opts = MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", response->token);

    opts.onSuccess = onDisconnect;
    opts.context = client;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_disconnect(client, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void onConnectFailure(void* context, MQTTAsync_failureData* response)
{
    printf("Connect failed, rc %d\n", response ? response->code : 0);
    finished = 1;
}


void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Successful connection\n");
    
    opts.onSuccess = onSend; // -> something like onHoldConnect???
    opts.context = client;

    pubmsg.payload = SendMessageArray; //PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(SendMessageArray);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    deliveredtoken = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTAsync client;
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    MQTTAsync_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);

    MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, NULL, NULL);

    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
    conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
    conn_opts.context = client;
    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Waiting for publication of %s\n"
         "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
         SendMessageArray, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    while (!finished)
        #if defined(WIN32)
            Sleep(100);
        #else
            usleep(10000L);
        #endif

    MQTTAsync_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

Here is the original code: http://gitlab.witium.com.cn/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/master/src/samples/MQTTAsync_publish.c

I somehow need a persistent connection to the broker sending all the new messages. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**:
Okay what I did now is
(1) hold the connection by not disconnecting after send:

```
void onHoldConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("Holding connection\n");
}

void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Successful connection\n");
    opts.onSuccess = onHoldConnect; //onSend;
    opts.onFailure = onSendFailure;
    opts.context = client;
    pubmsg.payload = SendMessageArray; //PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(SendMessageArray); 
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

and (2) run the onConnect function within the while loop with an global bool if the SendMessageArray has been modified:

```
while (!finished) {
    if (sendFlag == true) {
      sendFlag = false;
      onConnect(client, &conn_opts);
    }
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        Sleep(100);
    #else
        usleep(10000L);
    #endif
}
```

Is this the right way to solve the problem? I simply used (client, &conn_opts) as parameters again.

Comment: I was struggling with this as well, did it end up working for you?